# Which drive does the storage light refer to?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard

I'm referring to the "HDD light" that comes on most computers, which blinks or turns on during periods of storage activity.

However, despite being called the *HDD* light, it still works with an SSD or other storage device. When there are multiple drives it can become quite ambiguous which storage device the light is blinking for. The boot drive? The first HDD?

Is there a way to know which drive it refers to, and possibly change this setting?

Comment: All of them? IIRC it's always been like that.

Comment: You would have to install software to differentiate which drive is which. I use this software myself>>>>https://www.hddled.com/